# How to check if map is empty in Visualforce page on rendered

Tags: visualforce, map, rendered, empty

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!map.size > 0}" >
```

this doesn't work. gives the error:

> Unknown property 'map.size'

Comment: There's no documented way to do this. You will want to use a List instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like @sfdcfox says in the comments, there's no official way to do this. If your data type was a list, the `size` field is exposed to visualforce, but not for sets or maps.

You can get around this restriction by adding a variable to your controller to provide the size of your map on a get.

```
public Integer SizeOfMap { get { return SomeMap.size(); } } 

<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!SizeOfMap > 0}" >
```